# Blank page at retriving object in php

Tags: php

Here is var_dump($myfirstname);

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4836 (1) { ["meta_value"]=> string(7) "Some string" } }
```

But when i use echo $myfirstname->meta_value; it don't want to print.

Comment: That looks like you've got an array containing one object, not just an object. Try `$myfirstname[0]->meta_value`. As a side note, if you enable PHP errors, this should be raising a warning alone the lines of *Warning: Attempt to read property "meta_value" on array...*

Comment: thank you i got it